# Powershell: Search Replace XML with CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I am a beginner at PowerShell and scripting/programming but I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will search through each XML document in a directory for a value found in column 1 of a CSV file and replace that found value with the value in column 2 of the same CSV.  The script will then need to go to the next row of the CSV and repeat the process and continue until all values in Column 1 of the CSV have been searched for and replaced accordingly.

I've cobbled the following together but I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

```
$c = import-csv C:\somecsv.csv)
$xmls2search=get-childitem C:\somedirectory\*.xml
foreach ($xmldoc in $xmls2search)
{
  (Get-Content $xmldoc.PSPath) | 
  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $c[i].column1name, $c[i].column2name} | 
  Set-Content $xmldoc.PSPath
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your situation, I'd probably do something like this.

```
$c = Import-Csv yourcsv.csv

Get-ChildItem *.xml | Foreach-Object {
  # Out-String in the next line lets you work with a single string rather than an
  # array of strings.
  $xmldoc = (Get-Content $_.PSPath | Out-String)

  # Loop through your CSV, updating $xmldoc with each pass
  $c | Foreach-Object {
    $xmldoc = $xmldoc -replace $_.column1name,$_.column2name
  }

  # Write the updated $xmldoc back to the original XML file's path
  $xmldoc | Set-Content $_.PSPath
}
```